# Add active on parent li only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know onlu basic jQuery. I want to add active class on parent li by jQuery.

Live site- http://www.arif-khan.net/other/active/page1.html
Go to there then go to page2 under Support menu(http://www.arif-khan.net/other/active/page2.html). You can see code add active class on all li also with parent li(Support).
I need to modify that code so parent li(Support) will get active class instead of parent+all child li.

Code-

```
 <ol id="menu">
        <li><a href="Default.aspx" title="Home Page" style="color:#FFF">Home</a>        
        <li><a href="OverView.aspx" title="Overview">OverView</a>        
        <!-- sub menu -->
              <ol>     
                <li><a href="Technical-Info.aspx" title="Technical Info">Technical Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="End-Device-Info.aspx" title="End Device Info">End Device Info</a></li>
              </ol>
        </li><!-- end sub menu -->        
        <li><a href="Register.aspx">Register To Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="Rates.aspx">Rates</a></li>              
        <li><a href="#">Support</a>        
              <!-- sub menu -->
              <ol>     
                <li><a href="page2.html" title="Page2">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="TOS.aspx" title="TOS">Terms Of Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact_Us.aspx" title="Order the service">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ol>
        </li><!-- end sub menu -->        
        <li><a href="skype:nir2far?call" title="Call us on Skype">Skype</a></li>
    </ol>
```

jQuery-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ol#menu li a').each(function(index, element) {
    var li = $(element).attr('href');
    $(element).parent().removeClass("active");   
   var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    if(filename==li)
    {
            $(element).parents("li").addClass("active");
    }

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: $(element).parents("li").addClass("active"); should be parent instead of parents

Comment: Already tried with this, it add active class on "Page2" not in "Support".

Comment: If you add the class "active" on the "Support" li, all the li content will receive the red background. You should add the active class in the anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

The [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method selects all matching parent elements up the `DOM` tree. , You can use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) For selecting the immediate parent element and [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for selecting the first matching parent up the `DOM` tree.

So try

```
$(element).closest("ol").parent("li").addClass("active");
```

Instead of

```
$(element).parents("li").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Already tried with this, it add active class on Page2 not in Support.

Comment: It doesn't work. The `parent()` method returns an immediate parent. The first 'li' does not have an immediate 'li' as a parent. @arifix see my answer, please.

Comment: @FlavioEscobar your answer will activate all the `<li>`'s up the tree when if it grows and hence not ideal...

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
$(element).parent('li').parents('li').addClass("active");
```

instead of

```
$(element).parents("li").addClass("active");
```

Your anchor 'page2' is inside an 'li', so this is its direct parent. You must access the 'li's parent.